# How to rotate an image in a Metal Fragment Shader?

Tags: ios, fragment-shader, metal, image-rotation

this is what I've tried:

```
float ang = atan2(v - 0.5, u - 0.5) + (r / 360) * pi * 2;
float amp = sqrt(pow(u - 0.5, 2) + pow(v - 0.5, 2));
float2 uv = float2(sin(ang) * amp, cos(ang) * amp) + 0.5;
float4 c = inTexture.sample(s, uv);
```

The result is way off, it looks like the polygons of the quad are rotating in random ways, not good.

Anyone see a mistake I'm doing or know a more sleek way of achieving a simple rotation?

Thanks,
/Hexagons

Comment: What is the high-level goal you're trying to achieve? I think you may have [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to rotate an image, you would typically do that in the vertex shader (or even before that, in the attributes you feed into the vertex shader).

Comment: My goal is to rotate an image in a fragment shader as a part of an array/tree of multiple fragment shaders with different image effects.

Comment: @tmm1 check this out: https://github.com/heestand-xyz/AsyncGraphics/blob/main/Sources/AsyncGraphics/Graphics/Effects/Direct/Transform/Transform.metal

Comment: Thanks. Another option now available is `VTPixelRotationSession`